# Navigation Link Using a form SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, navigation

I want to move to another view using a button from a form, I'm trying to make a settings page.
The code below, I managed how to open a URL from a form, now I want to open another page but I didn't now how to do it.

```
struct FormRowLinkView: View {
        
        var icon: String
        var color: Color
        var text: String
        var link: String
        
        
        var body: some View {
            
            HStack{
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(color)
                    Image(systemName: icon)
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
                .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
                
                Text(text).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    guard let url = URL(string: self.link), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) else {
                        return
                    }
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
                }) {}
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                }
                .accentColor(Color(.systemGray2))
                
            }
            
        }
    
    
    struct FormRowLinkView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            FormRowLinkView(icon: "globe", color: Color.pink, text: "Website", link: "")
                .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 375, height: 60))
                .padding()
        }
    }
```

**This is how the Settings View looks like, I'm trying to code a button so the user can tap it to move to another page, i tried so many codes but with no luck**

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    
    // Properties
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    
    // Body
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                
                // Form
                
                Form{
                    // Section 3
                    Section(header: Text("Follow Us On Social Media")){
                        FormRowLinkView(icon: "person", color: Color.blue, text: "Profile", link: "")
                        FormRowLinkView(icon: "link", color: Color.blue, text: "Twitter", link: "")
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 3)
                    
                    
                    // Section 4
                    Section(header: Text("About the application")){
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "gear", firstText: "Application", secondText: "Todo")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "checkmark.seal", firstText: "Compatibility", secondText: "iPhone, iPad")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "keyboard", firstText: "Developer", secondText: "John / G")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "paintbrush", firstText: "Designer", secondText: "Robort")
                        FormRowStaticView(icon: "flag", firstText: "Version", secondText: "1.0.0")
                    }.padding(.vertical, 3)
                } // End of form
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
                
                // Footer
                Text("Copyright All rights reserved. \nSultan")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .padding(.top, 6)
                    .padding(.bottom, 8)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                
                
                
            } // End of VStack
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "xmark")
            }
            )
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
            .background(Color("ColorBackground").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))

            
            
        } // End of Navigation View
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should also go through [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) as this is extensively covered in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NavigationView` and inside of it you can use NavigationLink():

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var icon: String
    var color: Color
    var text: String
    var link: String
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(color)
                        Image(systemName: icon)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Text(text).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        guard let url = URL(string: self.link), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) else {
                            return
                        }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
                    }) {}
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))

                }
                .accentColor(Color(.systemGray2))
                
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Destination")
                } label: {
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8, style: .continuous)
                            .fill(color)
                        Image(systemName: icon)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 36, height: 36, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Text(text).foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct FormRowLinkView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(icon: "globe", color: Color.pink, text: "Website", link: "")
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 375, height: 60))
            .padding()
    }
}
```

I hope this works! If it is not working or its wrong, just comment.

Comment: No my friend it didn't work, please take another look to the question, I edited it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If u want to present a new screen add an @State var to your content view like this.

```
@State var isShowingSettingsScreen: Bool = false
```

Then add a button that looks something like this.

```
    Button {
        isShowingSettingsScreen = true
    } label: {
        Text("Show Settings Screen")
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isShowingSettingsScreen) {
        //The screen you want to present goes here <----
        Color.red
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `Form` into a `NavigationView`, then `NavigationLink` works inside.

```
struct SettingsView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Content Screen")
                    } label: {
                        Text("Content Button")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```